# Devise invitable and validating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have an app where users can invite other users, and I have added a `has_many` model `Enrollment` model that has several attributes.

The devise_invitable module seems to ignore validations, so in my case, if my nested attributes fail validation, it is never caught, and the user still gets invited.

I found the `validate_on_invite` (defaults to false) setting, which may work. But then, I would need to add conditional validations to the other `User` attributes (name, address, etc.) so that they do not trigger during the invitation process.

I have a custom create controller method right now, and can add some logic to check the presence of parameters, etc. However, is there an easier way to do this that relies on the model validations?

**UPDATE**

I tried changing `validate_on_invite` to true and got nested attributes and validations working.  The problem I have now is that in the `User` model you can't (as far as I can tell) do a conditional validation based on the controller action (i.e. the invitations controller with the create action).

I think I am back to some custom code in the invitations controller.

Comment: I have not tested it yet but I think I can accomplish this based on the ideas from this post: https://richonrails.com/articles/skipping-validations-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up stumbling upon `if: :accepted_or_not_invited?`.  I added this to all the `User` validations (other than email address).  I can invite users with nested enrollment attributes that are automatically saved.  I don't have the nested validations working yet but for not I added a monkey patch in my invitations controller to validate the enrollment params.